# What does the words in the terminal of linux mean?

Tags: linux, terminal, virtual-machine

I have a Linux VB running and was wondering what the syntax in the terminal meant.

What does each part mean?

```
user@user-vb:~$
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called PS1 prompt. Search for PS1 in your ~/.bash* files.

Usually it the:

`user` :- UserID
`@` :- Just a delimiter and it can be any other symbol also.
`user-vb` :- Name of the machine or hostname
`~` :- Present working directory - will change if you change to a different directory and `~` represents the `user` home directory.
`$` - prompt.

Comment: Do you know that the " | " means? E.g "ls | grep D"

Comment: It is called pipe. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix) for more info.